# Firefox DevTools :hover state disappears

Tags: firefox, hover, firefox-developer-tools

Trying to move from developing on Chrome to Firefox Dev Edition, and when I am in the Firefox DevTools, I'm triggering the hover state on an element but the state disappears as soon as I click any other element.

[image: Hover state disappears]

This is not happening in the Chrome DevTools, for example. The element is hovered until I cancel the hover state or reload the page.

I'm not interested in using jQuery to trigger the state.

How do I make it permanent? Is this supposed to be like this, or is it just a bug?

Comment: You obviously use the [Firefox DevTools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools), not [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you are seeing is indeed a bug in the Firefox DevTools, which is filed as [bug 1185797](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1185797).